# android - submit button inside webview not working despite enabling javascript

Tags: android, webview

I want to show a bank website application for paying online .I should use webview , this is my webview code :

```
WebView wb = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
WebSettings settings = wb.getSettings();
settings.setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");
settings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
settings.setSupportZoom(true);
settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
settings.setSaveFormData(false);
settings.setSavePassword(false);
settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
progressBar = ProgressDialog.show(Pay.this, Z_Farsi.Convert(getString(R.string.gettingdata)),               Z_Farsi.Convert(getString(R.string.wait)));

wb.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
        handler.proceed();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }

    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        if (progressBar.isShowing()) {
            progressBar.dismiss();
        }
    }
});
```

The problem is , it's going to a step that I need to click on a button to connect to paying web page . I don't know why it doesn't work and button doesn't press down .

I tested it on android default browser and it worked fine .

Could you help me ? Why does that button is not working on webview?